# which way is better to create setting screen in android

Tags: android, preferenceactivity, preferencefragment

I am new to android. My question is: Which way is better to create setting screen? I have read on google about `PreferenceFragment` or `PreferenceActivity` But I'm confused and don't know how many ways are there to create setting screen and which is best one. So my question is which is the best and recommended way to create setting screen? Please help

Comment: Those are the only two ways... Unless you want to create one by hand... Then there's infinite ways

Comment: It depends on your needs i think.

Answer (score 1):

If you're beginner use Preference `Fragment/Activity` it's fairly easy to use. But in old devices they not materialized So you can use library like [this](https://github.com/jenzz/Android-MaterialPreference) which backport Preference. Also if you need more functionality you should implement your own `Fragment/Activity` and put every things you want.

Comment: Is there any limitation using preference activity or fragment ? or i can create setting screen as i want

Comment: @FaisalAhmed The only limitation as I mentioned is in pre-lollipop devices they're not follow material design. Also they're extend from PreferenceFragment/PreferenceActivity which sometimes cause problem if you want to use Inherited from specific activity/fragment.

Comment: so i should not use preference for below pre-lolipop[below api level 21] . if my app support below api level 21

Comment: it's depends on situation. sometimes it's not important that your settings be like default android style in old devices and sometimes is important.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a beginner then create a new activity for your settings menu. It is easy to set up and will work on every device. You can call the settings screen by attaching what is called an `onClickListener` to a button. This is the easiest way for a beginner. Have fun!